# How do I sort data by the last update date in Cassandra?

Tags: database, cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, amazon-keyspaces

I need advice to correctly design the table in Cassandra. I need to get a sorted list of all the books. Sorting is performed by the date of the last update. Each time a particular book is purchased, the `number_of_buyers` column is updated. Also, I need to update the value of the `updated_at` column. The problem is the `updated_at` column is the `clustering key` which is the part of the `primary key`. We can't update values in columns that are part of the primary key.

```
create table books (
   book_id uuid,
   created_at timestamp,
   updated_at timestamp,
   book_name varchar,
   book_author varchar,
   number_of_buyers int,
   primary key (book_id, updated_at)
) with clustering order by (updated_at desc);
```

Another example:

```
create table chat_rooms (
   chat_room_id uuid,
   created_at timestamp,
   updated_at timestamp,
   last_message_content varchar,
   last_message_author varchar,
   unread_messages_number int,
   primary key (chat_room_id, updated_at)
) with clustering order by (updated_at desc);
```

Each chat room has the latest message. This information is always changing. In cases of change, I want to put the chat room at the top of the list. Classic behavior in many messengers.

Comment: You need to rethink an approach - sorting in Cassandra happens only inside partition, not between partitions, so the current model won't work for you. The real question that you need to ask - do you need this sorted list for all books, or only for some subset? Like, books sold during the day, or something like.

Comment: In my case, I need a list of all books. If any information about a particular book is updated I need to put it at the top of the list. To achieve this behavior, I have to recreate an entry in the table. That is, delete the record and create it again, but with updated data. I agree with you that there are problems with the design of the model. How would you redo the design of the model for this request?

Comment: what will be the query for that - pull all books? Do you really need Cassandra for that task, because all books would be easily handled by mysql or postgresql...

Comment: Try to abstract. Please check my post again. In place of books, there may be chat rooms. Each chat room has the latest message. This information is always changing. In cases of change, I want to put the chat room at the top of the list. Classic behavior in many messengers. I think Cassandra is not redundant here. Plus, you can get not all chat rooms, but only the last 100. Do you have any ideas now?

Answer (score 1):

So for sure; you are going to need to partition on something different.  The trick is going to be finding the right balance of query flexibility (your obvious need here) while avoiding unbound partition growth.

For the `books` table, is it possible to partition on something like `category`?  You know, like horror, fantasy, graphic novel, non-fiction, instructional, etc..?

```
CREATE TABLE book_events (
   book_id uuid,
   created_at timestamp,
   updated_at timestamp,
   book_name varchar,
   book_author varchar,
   number_of_buyers int,
   category text,
   PRIMARY KEY (category, book_name, updated_at, book_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (book_name ASC,updated_at DESC,book_id ASC);
```

For the PRIMARY KEY definition, we can partition on `category`, and then cluster on `book_name` and `updated_at`, with `book_id` on the end (for uniqueness).  Then, `INSERT` a new row for each sale event.  On the query (after inserting a few rows), use the `MAX` aggregation on `updated_at` while using the `GROUP BY` clause on `book_name`.

```
SELECT book_name,book_author,number_of_buyers,MAX(updated_at) FROm book_events 
 WHERE category='Computers & Technology' GROUP BY book_name;

 book_name                       | book_author                                                | number_of_buyers | system.max(updated_at)
---------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------------------
  Mastering Apache Cassandra 3.x |                                Aaron Ploetz, Teja Malepati |               52 | 2020-10-05 14:29:33.134000+0000
 Seven NoSQL Databases in a Week | Aaron Ploetz, Devram Kandhare, Brian Wu, Sudarshan Kadambi |              163 | 2020-10-05 14:29:33.142000+0000

(2 rows)
```

The only other consideration, is what to do with the obsoleted sale rows.  You could delete them as you go, depending on the write frequency, of course. The most-optimal solution would be to consider the cadence of sales, and apply a TTL.

This solution is definitely not complete as-is, but I hope it leads you in the proper direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I went a little bit the other way and I would be interested in your opinion. Thinking about it for the last couple of days, I realized that there is no perfect solution. I want to find the right balance.

Comment: I made a `book_id` column with the `timeuuid` data type. Then use it as the `clustering key`. I use the `category` column as the `partition key`. Only these two columns form the `primary key` for me. I update the information in the `updated_at` column every time there is a change with the book. Then, at the software level, I sort books by date in the `updated_at` column. In this case, a lot of load falls on the program and it is inconvenient to make a pagination. I have to upload all the data, but I don't have to delete records from the database. What do you think about it?

Comment: By the way, how do you do pagination in your version?

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek I like your solution.  It has the added benefit of leveraging the intrinsic functions within Cassandra (compaction) to remove obsoleted data.  Pagination wasn't really a consideration for my solution - was relying on the Driver's built-in row pagination.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately, I can't use the [driver's built-in row pagination](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.23/query_paging/) to solve this problem with my solution. Isn't it?